# Is this an vectorial space? $(\mathbb{R},+,\mathbb{Z},\times)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is this an vectorial space?

$(\mathbb{R},+,\mathbb{Z},\times)$

I think is a space vectorial because is closed in sum and multiplication, in other words:

Be $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$ then

1)$x+y\in\mathbb{R}$

2)$(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$

3)$\exists0\;:\;x+0=0+x=x\in\mathbb{R}$

4)$x+y=y+x\in\mathbb{R}$

5)$x+(-x)=(x-x)=0\in\mathbb{R}$

6)$x\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

7)$\alpha(\beta x)=(\alpha\beta)x\in\mathbb{R}$

8)$\alpha(x+y)=\alpha x+\alpha y\in\mathbb{R}$

9)$(\alpha+\beta)x=\alpha x+\beta x\in\mathbb{R}$

10)$\exists1\;:\;1x=x\in\mathbb{R}$

I think is a vectorial space, but i have dude with this, can someone help?

Comment: Vector spaces have scalars in a field (where division is always possible except for division by zero), but $\Bbb Z$ is not a field because dividing one integer by another may yield a number which is not an integer. However, if you relax the condition on the scalars that they only form a ring, not a field (so now division doesn't need to always be possible), you get a *module*. What you've shown is that $\Bbb R$ is a $\Bbb Z$-module.

Answer (score 2):

A vector space is an abelian group of elements that can be multiplied by scalars. The scalars must form a *field*, and $\Bbb Z$ is not a field.

If the "scalars" are in a ring, the "vector space" is called [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a vector space, because you need a field of scalars for a vectorspace and $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a field!